# Azure DevOps: Pipeline for all branches but master

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, devops

I have a website project with two pipelines

1.- PROD pipeline, which is triggered on every master branch push. This builds the site, deploys it and sends an email to the whole company informing about the new version. This works perfectly so far ✅

2.- DEV pipeline: should be triggered on a push to ANY branch that is not master. Builds the site, deploys the site to a DEV stage and sends an email to the author of the commit.

Following the docs, this trigger configuration should trigger the DEV pipeline on all branches but master.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    exclude:
      - master
    include:
      - '*'
```

However, if I then try run the pipeline in any branch that is not master, I get the following error: `Encountered error(s): Could not find valid pipeline YAML file for this branch/tag`

[image: Azure DevOps pipelines: Encountered error(s): Could not find valid pipeline YAML file for this branch/tag]

How can I setup the pipeline, so that it gets triggered by all branches but the master branch?

Thanks in advance for your help!

D

Comment: Just to confirm, your pipeline's yaml file does exist on branches other than master, right?

Comment: I think you should actually have azure-pipeline.yml file in each branch to not encounter this error.

Comment: Just so I understand you correctly, do you have two pipeline yaml files in your codebase right now? one that triggers on the master branch, and a seperate yaml file that is set to trigger for all branches except master?

Answer (score 1):

You have to have the YAML file in every branch you want it to trigger for, you cannot just have it in the master branch and expect it to trigger on another branch.